# Manually Managing Axes on python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was trying to achieve this

[image]

But i ended with this

[image]

The main idea was to manage axes to include the third subplot in the figure, but i can't find a way to do it. Can somebody help with that please.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-4*np.pi,4*np.pi,0.25)

np.sincx=np.sin(x)/x 

plt.figure(num=3, figsize=(7,5)) 
plt.subplot(3,2,1) 

plt.plot(x,np.sincx)

plt.subplot(3,2,2)

plt.plot(x,np.sincx,"ro")

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_axes((0.125,0.1,0.775,0.45))

plt.plot(x,np.sincx**2)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Dearsfs Asfrt. When running your code under Jupyter with Python 3, I am able to see the bottom figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are creating two figure, one with the two tops plots, and one with the bottom one. You need to only create one with multiple subplots!

```sh
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-4*np.pi,4*np.pi,0.25)
np.sincx = np.sin(x)/x 

ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax1.plot(x,np.sincx)

ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
ax2.plot(x,-np.sincx,"ro")

ax3 = plt.subplot(212)
ax3.plot(x, np.sincx**2)

plt.show()
```

##### Output

[image: plot]

##### With add_axes()

```sh
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-4*np.pi,4*np.pi,0.25)
np.sincx = np.sin(x)/x 

fig = plt.figure() 

ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax1.plot(x,np.sincx)

ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
ax2.plot(x,-np.sincx,"ro")

ax3 = fig.add_axes((0.125,0.1,0.775,0.45))
ax3.plot(x, np.sincx**2)

plt.show()
```

##### Output add_axes()

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, that helps a lot, i just have one more question, the problem suggest that it will be better if I use this line of code. ax=fig.add_axes((0.125, 0.1, 0.775, 0.45)). I really don't understand how can I implement it on the answer.

Comment: If you really want to use this line of code, you can add the line `fig = plt.figure()` before creating the subplots, and replace the line `ax3 = plt.subplot(212)` by `ax3 = fig.add_axes((0.125,0.1,0.775,0.45))`. But you will need to manualy tune the limits of your plot to look good. I'll edit my solution to include it too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was really stressing out with this, it was simpler than i thought hahaha. Greetings from Chile!